# How do you multiply a quanternion by a vector3 in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code:

```
private Transform player;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    player = Object.FindObjectOfType<PlayerIdentifier>().transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float newPosX = (Quaternion.AngleAxis(player.rotation.z, Vector2.up) * player.position).x;
    float newPosY = (Quaternion.AngleAxis(transform.rotation.z,Vector2.up)*transform.position).y;
    Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(newPosX, newPosY);
    newPos = newPos * Quaternion.AngleAxis(transform.rotation.z, Vector2.up);
    transform.position = newPos;
}
```

You see, I am getting an error on the 13th line saying that Quanternions cannot be multiplied by Vector3. Any way to multiply them without an error message?

Comment: FYI - wrote a quick reference on operations with quaternions - https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/23359/691

Comment: Did you want to transform a vector using the rotation stored in the quaternion?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou it was simply the order and OP missed to first ask the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, you have to put the Quanternion before the Vector3 Like this `Quaternion qua = Quanternion.Euler(0,0,90); Vector3 vect = new Vector3(0,1,0); Vector3 output=qua*vect;`

Comment: Show the code you used to solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).